# Makefile only include file if building rule

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
output.d:
    $(generate_deps)

include output.d
output: | output.d
    # ...

dep_a:
    # ...

dep_b:
    # ...
```

I don't know what the dependencies of `output` are until runtime.
These dependencies will need to be built before it, but I don't know if it's `dep_a`, `dep_b` (or even another) until after I've run `generate_deps` (which outputs `output.d` which has the dependencies)

The makefile works for this purpose, `generate_deps` is run, then `output.d` included and any dependencies built, and only after that is `output` built.

The problem with this, is that if I have any other target that doesn't depend on `output`, attempting to build it will still build `output.d`, which is a relatively expensive operation that should only be done if `output` needs to be built.

**How can I tell make to only include a file if a recipe needs to be built?**

Answer (score 0):

I have found an extremely convoluted way that seems to work.

It's based on recursing on the current makefile, where the recursed makefile actually builds the output.

```
output.d:
    $(generate_deps)

# Only actually include `output.d` if it's defined
ifdef OUTPUT_DEP
include output.d
endif

# When attempting to build `output`, check if `OUTPUT_DEP` if defined.
# If not, we're on the parent process and so we create a new process with the variable defined that only builds `output`.
# If we are, then we actually build it
output: | output.d
ifdef OUTPUT_DEP
    # ...
else
    @$(MAKE) "$@" OUTPUT_DEP=1 --no-print-directory
endif

# ...
```